# grails / log4j / conversion pattern / %throwable

Tags: grails, log4j

I use log4j 1.2.16 regarding my "dependency-report".

my Conversion Pattern is `'%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c: %m%n %throwable{short}'`

but `%throwable` is not recognized, instead the loglines contain

`'...hrowable{short}...'`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is in an appender?  Are you [using](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html) `EnhancedPatternLayout` (I believe you need that for `%throwable{n}`)

```
console name: 'stdout', layout: new EnhancedPatternLayout(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c: %m%n %throwable{short}")
```